# should I have split up my two-question question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I suppose I should have asked before editing, but when I wrote my question [How can I find out more information about the microfilms and indexes in the FHL, before I order the film?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/how-can-i-find-out-more-information-about-the-microfilms-and-indexes-in-the-fhl), in the midst of editing for clarity, it turned into two different question.  @PolyGeo gave me a gentle reminder that a question should only have one question in it, so I've split the original into two separate questions.

The upvotes are on the edit of the original, which is now titled [How can I find out if records in a FHL are available to view online?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/how-can-i-find-out-if-records-in-a-fhl-are-available-to-view-online)

The question which I should have written under the title [How can I find out more information about the microfilms and indexes in the FHL, before I order the film?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/how-can-i-find-out-more-information-about-the-microfilms-and-indexes-in-the-fhl) has been entered as a separate question.

Only after I split the question into two did it occur to me that there's no way to know why people upvoted the question, and their upvotes may not apply to the half of the question that they're attached to.  If it's appropriate to clear the upvotes and start over then please do so.

On the other hand, maybe it's better to roll things back so that the question is the way I wrote it originally.  In any case I'll try to write better questions in future.  I'm struggling a bit because if a question is too much like another one, SE complains, but I see the value of the basic principle of asking only one question at a time.

How should I have flagged the question as needing attention from a mod?

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about sorting the votes out -- once you've edited a question, people can change their vote or not, as they see fit. Nobody else (including moderators) can alter votes (except in very unusual circumstances such as voting abuse).

If you need to bring a question to moderator attention there's a 'flag' button under the question. However, this should only be used for things that can't be handled by the community as a whole via answers, comments, edits or up/down votes.

Comment: +1 I could not agree more that votes will sort themselves out & I commend @JanMurphy for teasing her questions apart.